# How to match content in json response in Postman?

Tags: json, regex, postman, visualize

Been trying to figure how to get regex working in Postman, but can't seem to zone in on what I'm doing wrong.

Sample:

```
{
    "start": 0,
    "end": 8,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "total": 9,
    "spam_count": 0,
    "newsletter_count": 9,
    "dataprotection_count": 0,
    "imagecontrol_count": 0,
    "dlp_count": 0,
    "compliance_count": 0,
    "mail_list": [
        {
            "id": "e1bc1808526fb75588281510a004e8e1c170a1f54bc3c93942d247021bfd3094",
            "metadata": {
                "email_date_received": 1665160705707,
                "quarantine_info": {
                    "direction": "inbound",
                    "quarantine_type": "NEWSLETTER"
                },
                "email_is_viewed": false,
                "email_is_released": false,
                "quarantine_reason": "AS",
                "email_sender": "Stu Sjouwerman (ssjouwerman@knowbe4.com)",
                "service_type": "ess",
                "master_recipient": "demo@domain.co.uk",
                "user_id": 16813960,
                "email_envelope_sender": "1axbtdwbzef4jmdi2c7gwtint0y4ht9y9ycw9p@241394m.knowbe4.com",
                "email_subject": "[FREE Resource Kit] The Cybersecurity Awareness Month Kit for 2022 is Now Available",
                "email_size": 74004,
                "email_envelope_recipient": "demo@domain.co.uk"
            },
            "actions": {
                "view_subject": true,
                "delete_message": true,
                "preview_message": true,
                "release_message": true
            }
        }
]
}
```

With the example below, I can get the ID fine when checking for an exact match, email size is 74004. But I've been trying to check for partials, like if the subject has a word, example instead of checking the email size, to check if the subject contains the word "Resource", or even via regex matching.

Tried pm.expect(counter.metadata.email_subject).contains("Password"); and also pm.expect(counter.metadata.email_subject).to.match(/Password/); but always get an error.

```
responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  var a=[];
  var schID;
  var list = (responseJson.mail_list).length;

console.log(list);
   for (var i = 0; i < list; i++) 
    {
    var counter = responseJson.mail_list[i];

    //pm.expect(counter.metadata.email_subject).contains("Password");
    //pm.expect(counter.metadata.email_subject).to.include("Password");

    if (counter.metadata.email_subject == "74004"){
        schID=counter.id
        a.push(schID)
    }

    }
    a= JSON.stringify(a)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

**Thanks @Onno**, works great.

Comment: The expect statements are not inside a `pm.test()` function so they wouldn't execute/be shown anywhere. You probably also want to use `===` for strict equality on the `if` statement too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Postman to run your code as a test, you have to wrap your function into a `pm.test` block, like so:

```
pm.test("Put a testname here", function() {
    // your code goes here
});
```

and then you can match the JSON body by putting your regex as the argument to the `.to.match()` function, e.g. this should pass

```
pm.test("Put a testname here", function() {
    const body = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(body.mail_list[0].metadata.email_subject).to.match(/Awareness/);
});
```